# PowerApps Detailed Analytics

Tags: powerbi, analytics, powerapps, usage-statistics

I'm working on a project for one my co-workers that involves PowerApps and analytics. They want to tracks how many people click on each link within their PowerApp, number unique clicks, number returning clicks and organization or location of each user. They asked for this information in some kind of dashboard/PowerBI format. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to get them that data. The "Analytics" function within PowerApps doesn't drill down to the specifics they're looking for. Open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data source (Sharepoint, SQL, etc.), you can create your own simple logging scheme. PowerApps makes it EXTREMELY easy to BYOT (Build Your Own Tools).

**Example:**

- `OnStart` of the app:

```
Set(varAppVersion, "0.90");
Set(varSessionGUID, GUID());
ClearCollect(colUserProps,
    {
        appVersion: varAppVersion,
        sessionGUID: varSessionGUID,
        userName: User().FullName,
        userEmail: User().Email
    }
)
```

- `OnVisible` of the first screen in your app
- (Assuming you have the `DATASOURCE` columns setup with the same naming convention and data types)

```
Patch(
    DATATABLE0,
    Defaults(DATATABLE0)
    colUserProps
)
```

- On each button `OnSelect` property just add...

```
Collect(
    colButtonsPressed,
    {
        buttonName: "whatever",
        pressed: Now(),
        sessionGUID: varSessionGUID
    }
)
```

- Finally, on the main "SUBMIT" button, add the above then...
- Again, assuming you setup `DATATABLE1` with the same column names as the collection and the same data types.

```
Patch(
    DATATABLE1,
    Defaults(DATATABLE1),
    colButtonsPressed
)
```

If you have access to your org's Azure tenant, look into [Azure Application Insights and PowerApps integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/application-insights).

**Note:** I think Azure Application Insights is in flux right now; renaming/rebranding/etc. so your mileage may vary for this part.